# How to get a WPF Toolbar to bind to a collection in my VM without using expander

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, toolbar

I have a WPF window that has a `ToolBar`.  I have a collection of objects in my VM that I'm binding to.  They appear as buttons but they always get pushed to the expanded drop down part of the `ToolBar`.  How do I make those buttons appear in the standard part of the `ToolBar`?

I have the following XAML:

```
<ToolBarTray Grid.Row="1">
    <ToolBar ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList}" >
        <ToolBar.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate  >
                <Button ToolTip="{Binding ButtonName}" 
                        Command="{Binding Path=ButtonCommand}" >
                    <Button.Content>
                        <Image Width="32" Height="32" Source="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
                    </Button.Content>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ToolBar.ItemTemplate>
    </ToolBar>
</ToolBarTray>
```

I have the following C#:

```
public List<MyClass> MyList
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<MyClass>
                       {
                           new MyClass{ButtonName="Button1",ImageSource=@"C:\Projects\WpfApplication2\WpfApplication2\Employee.png"},
                           new MyClass{ButtonName="Button2",ImageSource=@"C:\Projects\WpfApplication2\WpfApplication2\Employee.png"},
                           new MyClass{ButtonName="Button3",ImageSource=@"C:\Projects\WpfApplication2\WpfApplication2\Employee.png"},
                           new MyClass{ButtonName="Button4",ImageSource=@"C:\Projects\WpfApplication2\WpfApplication2\Employee.png"},
                       };

        }
    }
```

This is the visual result:

[image]

Comment: If I give the toolbar the static width of 500, the same visual result happens

Comment: Can you please be more specific

Comment: @Shimmy,  I don't think i can be more specific but I'll try.  I want those buttons that I have in my toolbar to show up in the standard (non-overflowed) part of the toolbar

Answer (score 4):

There is a bug in the toolbar, if you re-size the window, the problem goes away.

The solution is using another control, like:

```
public class WorkaroundToolBar : ToolBar
{
    private delegate void IvalidateMeasureJob();

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new IvalidateMeasureJob(InvalidateMeasure), 
                                     DispatcherPriority.Background, null);
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }
}
```

Check out [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/c5b6a94b-2cdc-4cfb-8ccb-0f7e680586d7) for more info

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work.  You are right though, when I resize the screen, the buttons appear as expected.

Comment: Works in my machine, try this barebones sample I made http://www.bizcacha.com/public/WpfApplication3.rar

Comment: This solution didn't work directly for me either. I haven't checked your supplied sample though.

Comment: Sorry Eduardo, my bad. This solution works. I forgot to replace `<ToolBar.ItemTemplate...` with `<WorkaroundToolBar.ItemTemp...` as well.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work completely. If the button-collection is empty at first, the application is launched and some buttons are added dynamically by code later the (Workaround)ToolBar is still visually invalid. It looks just like the screenshot above and redraws correctly as soon as the window is resized. Any more hints?

Comment: @Buthrankaur: Not tested, but I think that you may call the `IvalidateMeasureJob` again when you add buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the height of the toolbar in the xaml to a reasonable value which has worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Eduardo's, I had to slightly tweak this since my item source was getting populated asynchronously, some time after the initial UI is displayed:

```
public class ToolBar : System.Windows.Controls.ToolBar
{
    public override void OnApplyTemplate ()
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke ((Action)(InvalidateMeasure), DispatcherPriority.Background, null);
        base.OnApplyTemplate ();
    }
    protected override void OnItemsChanged (NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnItemsChanged (e);
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke ((Action)(InvalidateMeasure), DispatcherPriority.Background, null);
    }
}
```

This was enough to catch all edge cases and have the overflow properly happen as needed after population of the items.